# Why my regex not passing this case ( code included )

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match string that is  **greater than 5 characters long and have two consecutive digits.**

```
let pass = "ast3434";
let pwRegex = /(?=\w{5,})(?=(\d{2}))/; 
let result = pwRegex.test(pass);
console.log(result);
```

It returns true for "asd234asd"
but returns false for cases like "asd345" or "4543sdf"

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not match for "asd345" is that your use 2 assertions (non consuming) which both have to be true.

So there are no positions where there are AND 2 digits direclty on the right AND 5 word character directly on the right.

Is does match for `4543sdf` because both assertions succeed.

See [a demo](https://rextester.com/RHYY32611)

You could use anchors and use a single lookahead with a quantifier.

```
^(?=[^0-9]*[0-9]{2})\w{5,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UFYIGo/1)

Comment: ok i am satisfied with your answer. Just one thing, why use ^ at the start( i mean why check only at the beggning). It works without ^ also. See this [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UFYIGo/3)

Comment: It would also match without it, but the anchor at the start asserts that from the start there should be 2 consecutive digits in the string. If there are none, the match will fail and there is no need to check for it again. If you don't use the anchor, failing the expression will take more steps as the assertion will be run again for the next character.

Comment: Actually i was on FreecCodeCamp **Regex** section.  And it had the challenge to make a regex to *pass this case using 2 positive lookahead* , thats why i was using 2 lookaheads.  I found a way    `(?=\w{5,})(?=\D*(\d{2,}))`   
 Can it be made more efficient using 2 positive lookahead.

Comment: You don't need the capturing group around `(\d{2,})` and you can omit the comma as well like `(?=\w{5,})(?=\D*\d{2})`

Comment: Ohh got that Anchor point. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the time man and also for that site regex101.com . 2nd day of regular expressions. Loving it

Answer (score 1):

```
pass.length > 5 && /\d{2}/.test(pass)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\w{5}\d{2}/
```

---

^ begin with 
\w{5}  any word char, 5 times
\d{2} only digit : 2 times.


with capture sequence :

```
(^\w{5})(\d{2})
```

Comment: This will return false for `12345abcde`